# Is there a fast way for a user to delete all of their content?

Tags: support, comments, answers, questions, deleting

Let's assume that a user wishes to move away from TeX.SE and intends to delete all of the content they created up to the legally possible limit. Deleting tons of comments, unaccepted answers and unanswered questions is faster than creating them but doing it one-by-one is still a time-consuming operation; furthermore, there is a limit of 5 deletions per day on posts. Is there no *faster* way to do it?

Comment: You can delete as many comments as you want, and answers do not get *really* deleted, i.e. granted one has sufficient reputation one can see deleted posts as well, so your attempts to delete your unaccepted answers may not have the desired effect anyway.

Comment: Would be really cool if everybody would do that. Just bin everything. Nobody needs to see old stuff.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX.org. But a fair warning: There are just a small amount of people around. Very small amount.

Comment: Starting in 2008. With few people, i actually meant people that can answer a question. Not seek advice.

Comment: Just a note: [When is it kosher to delete one's own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216854)

Answer (score 4):

The only way to perform a speedy removal of content would be via programming. Support for this is provided through the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). Here you can delete a [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-question), an [answer](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-answer) and/or a [comment](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-comment), all of which require authentication (since you're only allowed to delete content if you're a/the permitted user). You are still [rate-limited](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle), but it will be much quicker than deleting the content manually.

Deleting your account is similar, but all content will remain, and all votes cast to individuals will be removed if the votes were legitimate votes and wouldn't cause too much disruption to the community. This is to avoid [high-voting users](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) (often high-rep users, but not always) from causing [reputation havoc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/168244).

Comment: "all votes cast to individuals will be removed if the votes were legitimate votes" reads as if they would not be removed if they were not legitimate. Please consider rewording this statement (unless this is what you want to say).